# SSIS Multiple Conditional Splits

Tags: ssis

I am new to creating SSIS packages.  I have a table on my database that has all the information I need.  I am trying to create an SSIS package that will split the data by Department and then by Month based on a date range.

I am to create the package to split the data into separate excel spreadsheets by department....however, I don't know how to further the package to also conditional split by month based on a date range as well as the department.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    Department
,   [Transaction Type]
,   Quantity
,   [Date/Time]
,   CASE
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-06-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2014-07-01') then 'June'
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-07-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2014-08-01') then 'July'
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-08-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2014-09-01') then 'Aug'
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-09-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2014-10-01') then 'Sept'
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-10-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2014-11-01') then 'Oct'
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-11-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2014-12-01') then 'Nov'
         when (cast([Date/Time] as Date)  >= '2014-12-01' and cast([Date/Time] as Date) < '2015-01-01') then 'Dec'
         else '' 
    END as Months
FROM [dbo].[DETAIL_DATA]
```

Basically, I would like to create an SSIS package that would put the data into an excel spreadsheet by department and by month.  Is it possible?

Comment: The MONTH() function is your friend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141258.aspx

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.....i also used DT_DBDATE, no luck.

Comment: You can't just put another conditional split on each of the outputs of your department Split?

Comment: @Artnette what do you mean it didn't work? Why can't you use [MONTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)?

Comment: which rdbms? SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use for loop or a foreach loop task, this will allow you walkthrough every department and every month to export them. You can start with one department and one month then try to generalise inside a loop for departments , keeping the month fixed; and finaly generalise the months in another loop.

The point is that as I see the request you need a loop instead of a conditional split.